# Problem modifying a library managed with yarn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, libraries, yarn-v2

Good morning,

I am facing a problem modifying a custom React library with yarn.

Another team from the university I work in have an npm private repository with some React components and we are using them to create a web which has to share the esthetic of the university website.

The problem is we have a "Provide Feedback button" in an Aside menu which contains a "mailto:xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx" link, but the mail address is hard coded when is supposed to be taken from a prop.

I fixed it in the library where the React Aside Menu is but React keeps taking the old library...

I tried to restart the yarn server, also do a "yarn cache clean", opening the web in a private navigation window... Nothing works...

I just want to try the change to open a Pull Request to let that fixed in the repository for the future...

Comment: Why not just publish the fixed package into your private NPM, delete the `node_modules` folder and do a `$ npm i`? Besides: NPM does not have "Pull Requests" - it isn't a VCS.

Comment: The npm repository is from another team, and I want to test my fix before I create the Pull Request at their GitHub repository so then it is updated in the npm repository.

Comment: Maybe just _ask_ someone from the other team how you should do it/they want it done? What I don't really get: You've written "I fixed it in the library ... " - does that mean you _already_ fixed it in _their_ library? Or did you modify what's inside _your_ `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Yeah, the second option, I forked the repository and I modified the library in the node_modules but wasn't able to test the change. 

I finally could test it but I do not know why suddenly it took the change deploying the app. 

I was trying more or less the same all the time, clearing cache and deploying...

I have been able to test it, the Merge Request approve, so everything it's ok now.